# Integrating Prometheus, Grafana and Azure

Tags: prometheus

I have hosted grafana and prometheus on localhost:3000 and localhost:9090
How can I check that my prometheus and grafana and synchronized. I want to use Prometheus in place of Log Analytics Workspace and store the logs and metric and display it on to Grafana. Please if any can share any referral document.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll find all the informations you need about Prometheus and Grafana in the official documentation of both product.

If you want to add Prometheus as a datasource in Grafana, have a look at [this page](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/)